# How to make drag and drop within Javascript (or another web language) with location detection

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, css

Have been working on this design for quite some time, trying to make a drag & drop system where I can detect where the golfball is.
I want to detect which circle/square it is in but also on what "coordinates" it is.
Have been making this in a couple of different systems, used Unity & Gamemaker for this, I have done it there with x & y system, detecting how far its in, but the problem there is that a samsung S3 for example has 1920 y and 1080 x, but a smaller phone with lower resolution has a different x and y, so i started using calculation for the width and height of the screen basicly trying to find the percentage. but because I didn't want to destroy the scale of the image that got really hard and inaccurate.

I am trying to redo this, but than in a better way, I haven't decided on the language yet but because I want to have a web app and android & ios I figured HTML + javascript in a ASP.NEt application to use Xamarin for Android & iOS delivery.

For the images:

Here I am trying to make a "green" this is where you are trying to land the ball.
[image: The green]

this is the ball: [image]

For what I have tried, you can find it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/43eat/15/ (found this sample, modified it a bit)

JQUERY

```
$("#snaptarget1").css("border-radius", "20%");
    $("#snaptarget2").css("border-radius", "30%");
    $("#snaptarget3").css("border-radius", "40%");
```

HTML

```
<div id="snaptarget1" class="bal-oszlop tapad bal"></div>
  <div id="snaptarget2" class="kozepso-oszlop tapad bal"></div>
  <div id="snaptarget3" class="jobb-oszlop tapad jobb"></div>
```

Comment: Android has Drag and Drop feature: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

Comment: I have noticed the android feature but I want to distribute to ios as well Altho I believe html 5 does as well but they do not detect where it is which is one of the main features